# Acceleration of masses hanging from a system of two pulleys

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, forces

> Masses $\mathrm{M_1}$ and $\mathrm{M_2}$ are connected to a system of strings and pulleys as shown. The strings are massless and inextensible, and the pulleys are massless and frictionless. Find the acceleration of $\mathrm{M_1}$.
>
> Clue: If $\mathrm{M_2} = \mathrm{M_1}$, acceleration ($A$) will be $A = \dfrac{g}{5}$
>
> [image: Question Image]

*Source: An Introduction to Mechanics – Kleppner & Kolenkow*

**My attempt:**

Let $T$ be the tension of the rope connected to $\mathrm{M_2}$. So the tension of the rope connected to $\mathrm{M_1}$ will be $2T$.
The acceleration of both the masses is $A$.

[image: Attempt Image]

Now,
$\mathrm{M_2}g - T = \mathrm{M_2}A \label{1}\tag{1}$

$2T - \mathrm{M_1}g = \mathrm{M_1}A \label{2}\tag{2}$

From $\ref{1}$ and \ref{2},

$$A = \dfrac{g(2\mathrm{M_2} - \mathrm{M_1})}{(2\mathrm{M_2} + \mathrm{M_1})}$$

Now if $\mathrm{M_2} = \mathrm{M_1}$,
I get,
$A = \dfrac{g}{3}$.

But the answer is $A = \dfrac{g}{5}$

Where am I wrong?
Will the accelerations of $\mathrm{M_1}$ and $\mathrm{M_2}$ not be the same? or, are there anything about the tensions ?

Comment: The tensions are correct. The problem is that you assume $a_1 = a_2$. If $M_2$ descends 1cm, how far does pulley 2 descend?

Comment: I think, if $M_2$ descends 1cm, then pulley 2(i.e the movable one) also descends 1cm and $M_1$ ascends 1cm as well. Isn't it? But how are the accelerations different?

Comment: The pulley would descend 0.5 cm. Think what happens if you just pull the pulley down 0.5 cm. That alone would cause $M2$ to descend 0.5 cm if the pulley did not rotate. But it does rotate, so $M2# descends farther than that.

Comment: If the accelerations are different let they are $A_1$ and $A_2$ for M1 and M2 respectively. Then the equations are $M_2.g–T=M_2.A_2$ … (i) and $2T–M_1.g=M_1.A_1$ … (ii). Now how to solve for $A_1$? OK it's a different question; pulleys are frictionless, so why do they rotate?

Comment: A frictionless pulley is one where the bearing at the center has no friction. The pulley rotates freely when the rope around it moves.

Comment: If $M_2$ moves twice as far as $M_1$, then its velocity is twice as big. And so is its acceleration.

Comment: Thank you @mmesser314 . If I take $A_2 = 2A_1$, then I find the correct answer i.e $A_1$ = g/5 . But I didn't understand how a massless frictionless pulley can rotate. I searched about it on google and found the link [link](http://okphysics.com/1-65-rotation-of-friction-less-pulley/) which clearly stated that "the (frictionless) pulley will be in rotational equilibrium"(i.e the pulley will not rotate). At [link](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=697623) there is a long discussion on this topic but after reading that I didn't get any conclusion. I am still searching ...

Comment: ... to get a clear explanation on the topic "massless and frictionless pulley" .

Comment: It doesn't matter whether a massless rope slides without friction over a non-rotating pulley or the rope moves without sliding over a massless pulley that turns freely. You can use either kind of idealized pulley for this problem.

Comment: A2 = 2A1.  If  mass 2 drops 2 cm, Pulley 2 drops 1 cm, taking in I cm of rope on the left and putting out I cm of rope on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start from the beginning. Why constraint relations? Why are they there? Let me emphasize :

Let's take origin at top pulley which is at rest.

[image]

Note that length of top rope is constant : $a+b=k\implies a''+b''=0 \implies a''=-b''$

Also Length of second rope is constant : $(c-b)+(d-b)=k\implies c''+d''=2b''$

Note that $d$ is a constant as the top pulley and ground is rest : $c''=2b''$

Hence, $c''=-2a''$ as stated in comments.

Also, everything we have done is futile and the block $M_2$ will hit the ground **very** quickly.

Comment: What does $a’’$ denote?